# UJS not working with XMLHttpRequest upload in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xmlhttprequest, multipartform-data, ujs

I have an application in Rails, where a user can post a new Post. In the form, I'm passing `:remote => true` so when the record is inserted into the database, the post is prepended to the view with javascript. So far, this is all working.

Recently I read [this](http://html5doctor.com/drag-and-drop-to-server/) article about how to drag and drop and automatically upload with HTML5 ([formData](http://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-XMLHttpRequest2-20100907/#the-formdata-interface)).

I have implemented this in a way that:

- drag and drop, works
- sending the attachment and handing it off to Carrierwave, works
- creating the new post with attachment, works

only where as before, when the post was created, Rails would render `create.js.erb` and prepend the newly created post, this doesn't work any more. The post is created in the database and if I hit reload, the post shows like normal. But the prepending javascript action in `create.js.erb` isn't executed.

`application.js`

```js
var doc = document.documentElement;

doc.ondrop = function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var files    = event.dataTransfer.files,
      formData = new FormData(),
      xhr      = new XMLHttpRequest();

  formData.append('authenticity_token', $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content'));

  for (var i=0; i < files.length; i++) {
    formData.append('post[image]', files[i]);
  };

  xhr.open('POST', '/posts', true);
  xhr.onload = function() {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      console.log('all done: ' + xhr.status);
    } else {
      console.log('Something went wrong...');
    }
  };

  xhr.setRequestHeader('accept', '*/*;q=0.5, text/javascript');
  xhr.send(formData);

}
```

`posts_controller.rb`

```rb
def create
  @post = Post.create!(params[:post])
end
```

`create.js.erb`

```js
$('<%= j render @post %>').hide().prependTo('.posts').fadeIn();
```

the terminal shows that the request it is processed as JS:

`Processing by PostsController#create as JS`

and my partial and ujs file is also rendered:

`Rendered posts/_post.html.erb (6.4ms)`

`Rendered posts/create.js.erb (7.9ms)`

---

**EDIT**

allright, I figured out my problem and it was something I didn't covered here. I'm also using [Pusher](http://pusher.com/) to publish the posts to all clients listening. Somehow the [Pusher gem](http://github.com/pusher/pusher-gem) prevented the UJS from rendering in the browser.

So the above code *does* work with Rails 3. I hope I can help someone who wants to try HTML5 drag and drop upload with this.